# C cast using pjsip

Tags: c, casting

I have few experience developing C applications and I am having a specific cast problem. 
I have a char variable hard coded that I need to pass as a parameter in a function.

```
char * data = "058dd54970d65c";

This is the function:

PJ_DECL(pj_status_t) pjsua_call_make_call(pjsua_acc_id acc_id,
                  const pj_str_t *dst_uri,
                  const pjsua_call_setting *opt,
                  void *user_data,
                  const pjsua_msg_data *msg_data,
                  pjsua_call_id *p_call_id);
```

In order to use it:

```
pjsua_call_make_call(acc_id, &uri, 0, NULL, data, NULL);
```

As you can see I need a cast in the parameter 5. I am getting this error:

note: expected `const struct pjsua_msg_data *` but argument is of type `char *`

I try to use sprintf and other solutions but do not work. I would be gratefull if somebody could help me.

Comment: Create a new object of `pjsua_msg_data` and fill your data into the msg_body.

Comment: I create this object pjsua_msg_data data_alice; How can I fill it or cast  with data="058dd54970d65c"

Comment: Try this`data_alice.msg_body = data;`

Comment: thank you! it works and I understand it

Comment: You are welcome. I add this as a new answer. Please accept and vote the answer.

Answer (score 2):

*For completion i write my comment as new answer.*

Create a new object of the `pjsua_msg_data` struct and fill your data into the `msg_body` property. After that you can simply use this object with the `pjsua_call_make_call` call.

Try this:

```
pjsua_msg_data data_alice; 
data_alice.msg_body = data;
pjsua_call_make_call(acc_id, &uri, 0, NULL, data_alice, NULL);
```